# What does each Country Bonus mean?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

If you launch a satellite for every country in an area you get a "Bonus" ... I can't find it in the XCOM Database. Mousing over doesn't show it. Is it listed somewhere?

- North America: Air & Space
- South America: We Have Ways
- Africa: All In
- Europe: Expert Knowledge
- Asia: Future Combat

I picked Europe as my starting country so I know that Expert Knowledge is a research credit of some kind. But most of the other countries weren't available to me. Is this information accessible somewhere without starting a new game?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I've had a similar problem finding this in-game once you've made your initial choice, but the benefits are:

- **"Air and Space"** - aircraft maintenance/cost is reduced by 50%.  You can create interceptors for cheaper, and their monthly fees are reduced.
- **"We Have Ways"** - Interrogations an autopsies complete instantly.  autopsies provide certain projects and gear, which typically requires corpses.  Interrogations typically yield research bonuses.
- **"Expert Knowledge"** - Labs and Workshops cost 50% less to build and maintain.  Labs grant scientists and speed up research.  Workshops grant engineers and can reduce the cost of buildings.
- **"Future Combat"** - 50% discount on in the Foundry and Officer Training School projects.  The Officer Training School bonus is pretty nice in the early game, and there are a few "gear improvements" in the Foundry that can be useful.
- **"All In"** - Monthly income is increased by 30%.  This means that at the end of the month, when you collect your income, it will be boosted, allowing you to build/buy more things in any given month.

I've given sort of a high-level interpretation of how the bonus would effect your game, but you'd probably want to play a bit or do some further research to fully understand the side effects.  For instance, a certain number of engineers is required for many engineering projects, and there's the notion of adjacency bonuses, and etc.

Note that you can also get another continent's bonus by having satellites over every country in that continent.  Getting additional continent bonuses also requires that countries in that continent do not leave the alliance.

Comment: These benefits can be seen while choosing a country in which to found the XCOM base.

Comment: @SaintWacko, right.  I don't think you can see them from the situation room view though, yeah?  It's a little tough to tell what the bonuses are when you're, say, planning satellite coverage.

Comment: Yeah, it would have been very convenient if you could just mouse over the bonus when you are deciding whether to finish the satellite coverage for North or South America first... Having to Save, Exit, Start anew, and Reload just to find out is a bit of a pain.

Comment: @agent86 Right, I'm just saying that's where that information comes from.

Comment: Also, it's worth mentioning is that number of countries differs per continent:  South America - 2; North America - 3; Africa - 3; Europe - 4; Asia - 4;  This has two implications: amount of satellites needed for full coverage differs, and more countries - more chances for one of them to go into high panic and leave.

Comment: And yes, We Have Ways is *exactly* as useless as it sounds.

Comment: @vartec that's interesting.  I don't remember that being called out in the help text for the bonus, was it and I just missed it?  Or is it undocumented?  Other sites seem to confirm what you've said, at least with Uplink/Nexus maintenance and/or costs.  I'll have to do some more research later to make sure I've got it just right in the answer.

Comment: @agent86: my bad, just checked it. Air and Space does not lower the cost of satellites. Which makes it way less useful. Apparently I've got the cost down by having a bunch of engineers

Comment: We have ways is no useless. It accelerates the game time and allows you to research other things instead. Infact it is extremely useful to have early game at Classic and Impossible difficulties.